# C#. Given an Enumerator, iterate till end to produce an enumerable

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

In C#, I would like to write an extension method that would take an `Enumerator<T>` and give back an `IEnumerable<T>`. This could prove useful, for example, if I had to enumerate to some point in a list and then want a list with current element (if enumeration has started) plus the remaining elements.

Here's a simple implementation I started out with

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Enumerate<T>(this IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
  {
      do
      {
          yield return enumerator.Current;
      }
      while (enumerator.MoveNext());
  }
```

Problem I am having is that if enumeration hasn't already started then this would add a default value of T to the sequence (as its first element). Is there any way to work around this/ without having to pass in additional arguments.

Comment: `This could prove useful, for example, if I had to enumerate to some point in a list and then want a list with remaining elements.` -- [Enumerable.SkipWhile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=net-6.0) will accomplish the same result, without having to write a new extension method.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: he has an enumerator which is partially enumerated. How does SkipWhile help to enumerate the rest without enumerating the first part again?

Comment: Change it to a while loop? You are supposed to `MoveNext` *first*, then get the current element. Not that I don't agree with Robert Harvey though. You could just use `Skip` or `SkipWhile`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: `myOriginalList.SkipWhile(some condition).ToList()`  (or `myOriginalList.SkipWhile(some condition)` if you just want the new Enumerable).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Where did the enumerator come from in the first place? Very likely an `IEnumerable<T>`. Robert Harvey is saying that OP could just call `SkipWhile` on that `IEnumerable` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I wasn't keeping count of number of items already enumerated.  @Sweeper,  if enumeration had already started then calling MoveNext would skip an element.   It may not indeed be possible to figure this out from the Enumerator alone, I might have to pass in a Boolean to indicate if Enumeration has started. Alternatively, keep count and use SkipWhile method.

Comment: No it wouldn't. The element that is skipped by calling `MoveNext` the first time is one that the caller has already enumerated over, and should not be included in the final `IEnumerable<T>` anyway. You might be using these interfaces incorrectly if you are expecting something else...

Comment: Why would using `SkipWhile` require you to keep a count? You pass in a condition telling it when to stop. `Skip` is the one that needs a count.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, I need the current element (if enumeration has started) plus the remaining elements.  I can achieve the same with various other Linq methods, but my question was more specific to just having an enumerator.

Comment: "Is there any way to work around this/ without having to pass in additional arguments." -- no. Whether or not `Enumerable.MoveNext` has just been called, or is about to be called, is not recorded anywhere, and since you need to distinguish between these states, it's going to have to be supplied one way or another. Having said that, this method isn't useful if you know enumeration hasn't started yet, since you can simply use the original `IEnumerable` in that case, so you may as well assume it will never be called under those circumstances (and, of course, don't actually call it).

Answer (score 0):

You need the `.MoveNext()` call before the `yield` statement.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Enumerate<T>(this IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return enumerator.Current;
    };
}
```